# Can't get media file from internal storage?

Tags: android

I use this code to get list media file from internal storage but it's not working. I am sure I have some mp3 file in my internal storage.
Cursor just query media files like ringtones, alarms, notifications.They are not what I need. I want to query media files I copied from my pc or download from internet.

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST };
    try {           
        Cursor cursor2 = activity.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                selection, null, null);
        while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
            String file_name2 = cursor2.getString(0);
            String file_path2 = cursor2.getString(1);
            String title2 = cursor2.getString(2);
            String artist2 = cursor2.getString(3);
            SongtoDisplay s2 = new SongtoDisplay(file_name2, file_path2,
                    title2, artist2);
            if(checkMp3(file_name2))
            {
                songtoDisplays.add(s2);
            }               
        }
        cursor.close();
        cursor2.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Comment: What error you are receiving or exactly what is happening?

Comment: Ok, i have edit my question.